A request for online source of nusach Arizal (chabad tehilas Hashem) other than Sefaria
Where can I find a test based copy of nusach Arizal (chabad tehilas Hashem) online other than Sefaria, which only has weekday prayers but not brachos.

Your question is difficult to understand. But if I understand what you are asking for, you should look to the nusach as found by Rabbi Shabbtai of Rashkov or Rabbi Yaacov Koppeler. Both can be found at Hebrewbooks.org

@YaacovDeane neither of those will be in text and I suspect though don't know for certain that adding the qualifier of these specific rabbis the siddurim will have some differences. Even if they aren't so big it makes a difference to me.

There are copies of סדור תהלת ה׳ on HebrewBooks (example), but I understand you are specifically looking for something text-based, where you could easily copy and paste. In that case, I advise you to check out this transcription of סדור תורה אור on OpenSiddur.

This siddur is not longer available in this website. Also two things. Torah ohr is a siddur that has a lot missing from it and so it won't be as helpful. I am editing my question to be more specific. It's been a while since I've gone into the sugya of the history of the siddur but Torah ohr was not the siddur from the alter Rebbe which did not have a name attached to it. I'm not saying different nusach but it was a different print edition.

@Dude It is the siddur the Rebbe himself davened from. Not sure how much more authentic Lubavitch nusach you can get. All the Chabad Chasidim used Siddur Torah Ohr prior to the first printing of Siddur Tehilas Hashem in the 1940s.

I never said it wasn't authentic
